# Deferred array initialization

Tags: c

Is there a way to delay the array initialization. For example, instead of doing:

```
int array[2] = {1,2};
```

To do:

```
int array[2];
array = {1,2}; // possible to do with some sort of cast or other?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An array cannot be assigned to directly.

You would either need to assign each element individually, or use `memcpy` along with a compound literal of the proper type.

```
memcpy(array, (int[2]){1,2}, sizeof(array));
```

Comment: thanks, is that technique used? Or it's overkill and you were just showing an example of how it might be done.

Comment: @David542 Depends on your use case.

Comment: I see, what would be an example where it might be useful to use that approach?

Comment: @david542: what's an example of a use case where you would want to separate the declaration and the initialisation of an array? (As per your question)

Comment: @rici just academic to see how/if possible.

Comment: @david: my point is, you asked how to do X. Someone generously tells you how could do it. *You* then ask for a plausible use case for X, the very thing you asked how to do. Maybe it's just me, but that seems kinda odd.